# Inner promise returning a catch

Tags: javascript

Will  the promise rejection that is returned inside catch gonna get received outside of the outer promise?

```
promisedFunction().then((result) => {
    return anotherPromisedFunction().then((result) => {
        ....
    }).catch((error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    //catch inner error here
});;
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Why would you ask without testing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *then* method returns a Promise, in your case, you are returning a rejected promise, so yes, the outer catch should handle that.

Comment: yeah i tested it on fiddle